# cant add setting with fluent in one-to-one - ef codeFirst

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, fluent

I have the following classes:

> ```
> User, Address, UserAddress
> ```

```
public class User
{
  public ICollection<useraddress> userAddresses { get; set; }
}

public class Address 
{
  public virtual User User { get; set; }
  public virtual Guid UserId { get; set; }
  public  UserAddress UserAddress { get; set; }
}

public class UserAddress
{
  public User User { get; set; }
  public Guid UserId { get; set; }
  public Address Address { get; set; }
  public Guid AddressId { get; set; }
}
```

My result should look like this :
[image]

I create following fluent configuration in `UserAddressConfig` :

```
HasKey(row => new { row.UserId,row.AddressId});
```

and `AdddressConfig` :

```
HasOptional(row => row.UserAddress).WithRequired(row => row.Address).WillCascadeOnDelete();
```

but when I generate the database it looks like:
[image]

Comment: Why do you store a `UserId` in `Address` instead of in `User`? That does not make sense to me.

Comment: @Wimmel its Foreign Key

Comment: Your models look off. First, they don't match the tables created (see Address). You refer to "row.osman" in the fluent code. What is that? Cutting to the chase, it looks like EF is adding Address_Id because you don't have your foreign keys configured correctly.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620.aspx#CompositeKey

Answer (score 1):

you can use this :

```
public class User
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("User")]
    public ICollection<UserAddress> UserAddresses { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public Guid AddressId { get; set; }

    public UserAddress UserAddresses { get; set; }
}

public class UserAddress
{
    public Guid AddressId { get; set; }

    public Address Address { get; set; }


    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    [InverseProperty("UserAddresses")]
    public User User { get; set; }

    public Guid UserId { get; set; }        

}
```

and in configuration with fluent api :

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Address>().HasRequired(c => c.UserAddress)
 .WithOptional(c => c.Address) // or any other option
 .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

but you can also have one to many relation between user and address like below:

```
public class User
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("User")]
    public ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public Guid AddressId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    [InverseProperty("Addresses")]
    public User User { get; set; }

    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
}
```